# VBA Error while trying to delete rows that contain 0

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro to delete every row where the value of its cell in column AN is 0.

This is the code I used:

```
Sub DeleteRow()

Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row

For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
If Cells(r, "AN") = 0 Then
Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next r

End Sub
```

This code produces a 'mismatch' error for the "If Cells(r, "AN") = 0 Then" line. How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: What is the value of `r` when you get this error?  And what is in the cell that corresponds to that row of column AN?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Range` instead of `Cells`.

```
If [ActiveSheet.]Range("AN" & r) = 0 Then
```

Note that you should always qualify `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns`, and `Names` member calls with a proper `Worksheet` object reference - otherwise you are implicitly working off whatever worksheet happens to be the `ActiveSheet`, and that has a tendency to cause errors whenever the active sheet isn't the one that the code is assuming. Unless the code is written in a worksheet's code-behind - in which case the implicit qualifier is `Me`, and it doesn't hurt to make it explicit.

But that won't solve the problem.

The problem is that you are assuming that the cell you're reading contains a value that is legally comparable to `0`. When comparing a cell value to `0` or `""` throws a *type mismatch* error, look at the worksheet: in all likelihood there are `#N/A` or `#VALUE!` worksheet errors.

Worksheet error values are a special data type: `Variant/Error`, and values of that data type cannot be compared to anything other than `Variant/Error` values - a *type mismatch* error is raised otherwise.

So, make sure you're not looking at a cell error before you do anything with the value:

```
If Not IsError([ActiveSheet.]Range("AN" & r).Value Then
    'safe to compare
    If [ActiveSheet.]Range("AN" & r).Value = 0 Then
       '...
    End If
Else
    Debug.Print "'AN" & r & "' contains a cell error"
End If
```

Comment: I set the worksheet as ws, so I am using < If ws.Range("AN" & r).Value = 0 Then > but this is bringing up the error "method range of worksheet failed". I am very new to VBA so please bare with me

Comment: @isaaacs make sure `r` is greater than zero